# Issue in the Dockerfile when deploying a Django App on GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine, dockerfile

I am trying to use a custom image of Dockerfile to deploy my Django App on GAE. I am following the [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime#kubernetes-engine--other-docker-hosts) provides by Google. However I have an issue on the last step :

`CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app`

I have tried several things but it keeps saying my module is not found.

What I have tried:

`CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT wsgi:app`

`CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT mydjangoproject/wsgi:app`

`CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT mydjangoproject.wsgi`

---

Dockerfile:

```
FROM solalsab/clarins:1.0.1

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
# Use -p python3 or -p python3.7 to select python version. Default is version 2.
RUN virtualenv /env

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app

# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

---

Structure of the project:

```
+myproject/
 +mydjangoproject/
 | +wsgi.py
 | +...
 +app_template.yaml
 +generate_app_yaml.pu
 +manage.py
 +requirements.txt
 +Dockerfile
```

---

The Error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
[2019-03-06 11:15:47 +0000] [6] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-03-06 11:15:47 +0000] [6] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (6)
[2019-03-06 11:15:47 +0000] [6] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-03-06 11:15:47 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2019-03-06 11:15:47 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
[2019-03-06 11:15:47 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
[2019-03-06 11:15:47 +0000] [6] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-03-06 11:15:47 +0000] [6] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Check where your source is added to. Dockerfile says `ADD . /app`.

Comment: I left `ADD. /app` as it is. But my Django app don't have a module named main. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Can you add the folder structure of your project?

Comment: I'm saying: non of your attempts respects docker folder structure. What is `WORKDIR` (working folder) here? Where is your myproject.wsgi file located?

Comment: I have updated my question so I added the structure of the folder (I tried to include only the relevants files) and I added my complete Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded to make it work by running:

CMD cd app; exec gunicorn mydjangoproject.wsgi

Answer (score 0):

The `main:app` part may have been taken from some other code sample (like [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/django)) where a main.py file is added to reference your app. In your case, you can create that `main.py` file in your root directory and add:

```
from mydjangoproject.wsgi import application

app = application
```

Or just update your Dockerfile like so:

```
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT mydjangoproject.wsgi
```

Comment: I have followed your advise on writing a main.py in the root. And wrote in my Dockerfile `CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app`. However it still sais it can find the module `main`. I guess the issue doesnt come the `CMD` line ?

Comment: maybe the issue comes from the "app_template.yaml" file ?